# Adding an enum to a list of a specific class c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, enums

I am trying to add an value of an enum into a list of a specific class type.

This is my class:

```
class Vak
{
    public string naamVanVak;
    public int theorieCijfer;
    public enum PraktijkBeoordeling
    {
        Geen, Absent, Onvoldoende, Voldoende, Goed
    }
}
```

This is my list where i need to add my enumeration into:

```
            List<Vak> rapport = new List<Vak>();
```

Here is where the enum gets decided:

```
Vak.PraktijkBeoordeling LeesPraktijkBeoordeling(string vraag)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(vraag);
            string invoer = Console.ReadLine();

            Vak.PraktijkBeoordeling praktijkBeoordeling = new Vak.PraktijkBeoordeling();

            if (invoer.ToLower() == "geen")
            {
                praktijkBeoordeling = Vak.PraktijkBeoordeling.Geen;
            }
            else if (invoer.ToLower() == "absent")
            {
                praktijkBeoordeling  = Vak.PraktijkBeoordeling.Absent;
            }
            else if (invoer.ToLower() == "onvoldoende")
            {
                praktijkBeoordeling = Vak.PraktijkBeoordeling.Onvoldoende;
            }
            else if (invoer.ToLower() == "voldoende")
            {
                praktijkBeoordeling = Vak.PraktijkBeoordeling.Voldoende;
            }
            else if (invoer.ToLower() == "goed")
            {
                praktijkBeoordeling =  Vak.PraktijkBeoordeling.Goed;
            }
            return praktijkBeoordeling;

        }

    }
```

Currently what im trying to do is:

```
void LeesRapport(List<Vak> rapport, string vraag, string vraag2, string vraag3)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Vak vak = LeesVak(vraag);
            rapport.Add(vak);

            Vak theorieCijfer = LeesCijfer(vraag2);
            rapport.Add(theorieCijfer);

            Vak praktijk = LeesPraktijkBeoordeling(vraag3);
            Console.WriteLine("Geen, Absent, Onvoldoende, Voldoende, Goed");
            rapport.Add(praktijk);
        }
    }
```

Obviously this isnt working but how can i make this work?

thanks in advance

Comment: How is this "not working"?  And what does this have to do with the `enum` in your class?

Comment: Can you write your code in english? if It is english than human readable english

Comment: There´s nothing to be changed in your loop, because `vraag1`, `vraag2` and `vraag3` will always stay the same. So you´re effectivly adding the same elements three times into your list.

Comment: Your `List` is holding class instances. If you want it to hold enum values then shouldn't it be `List<PraktijkBeoordeling>`?

Comment: Declare enum outside the `Vak` class. Then change last member to: `public PraktijkBeoordeling practijkBeoordeling;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant add them like this. Follow this example

Generate Class with Enum getter and setter that you missed:

```
public class Vak
{
    public string naamVanVak { get; set; }; 
    public int theorieCijfer { get; set; };
    public PraktijkBeoordeling enumPraktijkBeoordeling { get; set; }; //you need to add this one

    public enum PraktijkBeoordeling
    {
        Geen, Absent, Onvoldoende, Voldoende, Goed
    }
}
```

then out of your main add a list

```
List<Vak> rapport = new List<Vak>();
```

populate the list:

```
private void LeesRapport(List<Vak> rapport, string vraag, string vraag2, string vraag3)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Vak vak = new Vak();

            vak.naamVanVak = "data";
            vak.theorieCijfer = 1111;
            vak.enumPraktijkBeoordeling = LeesPraktijkBeoordeling(vraag);
            rapport.Add(vak);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this helps me a lot, i got rid of all the errors while writing the code, however i need to use my `Vak LeesCijfer(string vraag)` to fill `vak.theorieCijfer` instead of the `1111` is there a way to do this?

Comment: sure, you have to check that LeesCijfer returns an int and you can call it like this:vak.theorieCijfer = LeesCijfer(vraag)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to add a `Vak.PraktijkBeoordeling` to the list, while it is a list of `Vak`. 
Maybe you want to return a `Vak`, which has a `PraktijkBeoordeling` from `LeesPraktijkBeoordeling(string vraag)`?

Comment: Yes I am trying to add a `Vak.PraktijkBeoordeling` to a list of `Vak`, is this possible? And yes i need to get back a `Vak` with a `PraktijkBeoordeling from `LeesPraktijkBeoordeling(string vraag)`

Comment: Right now the `LeesPraktijkBeoordeling(string vraag)` doesn't return a `Vak`. Create a `Vak` inside the function, probably like you do in     LeesCijfer(vraag2) ? Then also replace the return type of the funtion to Vak